# Using Redux to avoid pulling data over again unless API data has been changed

Tags: react-native, redux

I am working on a React Native app where i'm using Redux to pull data from an API. Now, i just want to make the component re-render when API data changes. It should not change if the API data is same as earlier. How can i achieve that with Redux?

Comment: Try memoization - either `useMemo` or `reselect` - https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Comment: `i just want to make the component re-render when API data changes` how would you know if api data changed, what if **someone else** changes the data?

Comment: That's the point. I want to re-render whenever API data changes. How to catch the change ? @HMR

Answer (score 0):

I have done this successfully using the **useSelector** hook:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

Keep your redux store updated with the data from your API. The hook will fire whenever data in your redux store changes, allowing any component to be re-rendered when your redux store changes.

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const apiData = useSelector(state => state.apiDataLocation);

  /*This will update to display the api data whenever the 
  store is updated.*/ 
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{apiData}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: So, to catch changes from the API, does redux needs to send API requests constantly? If that so, how should i do that? I mean what is the best approach? @MattT

Comment: Generally speaking you should not be sending API requests constantly, which technology(s) are you using for your API? You may be able to listen for database changes in real time, but typically the API call is made on page load or some other action. This is just the front-end code to re-render from those changes.